# How to run functions which accept structs as input parameters from tondev?

Tags: solidity, everscale

For example, I have a function

```
function addClaimers(ClaimItemImport[] claimItems) onlyOwner external
```

and the ClaimItemImport struct looks as follows:

```
struct ClaimItemImport {
    uint128 balance;
    uint256 claimAddress;
}
```

How to call it from `tondev` with parameters?

This does not work:

`tondev contract run Contract.abi.json --address XYZ addClaimers -i claimItems:[[123, 0x123], [456, 0x456]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    --address 0:540c1837656674d548c934258ddec9b5fd11b543da977b0016c14b5650bc7eb5 \
    --input '{ "point": { "color": "red", "center": { "x": 1, "y": 2 } } }'
```

Check readme in the end of this section https://github.com/tonlabs/tondev#run-contract-deployed-on-the-network

Comment: Ok, I've changed to {} notation and added names, so it became:

`tondev contract run FidosafeDAO.abi.json addClaimers --address 0:2540afc97408aec8e094eaf2695acd8fd4c301830590214be584e4b627e5bf90 -i claimItems:[{"balance":0,"claimAddress":0}]`

The system responds with: Error: Unexpected argument claimItems:[claimAddress:0]

If I use this: `tondev contract run FidosafeDAO.abi.json addClaimers --address 0:2540afc97408aec8e094eaf2695acd8fd4c301830590214be584e4b627e5bf90 -i 'claimItems:[{"balance":0,"claimAddress":0}]'`

It responds with:
#FailureMessage Object: 00000090C6EFE940

Answer (score 1):

I've updated my tondev + used the following syntax:

```
tondev contract run FidosafeDAO.abi.json addClaimers --address 0:2540afc97408aec8e094eaf2695acd8fd4c301830590214be584e4b627e5bf90 -i '{"claimItems":[{"balance":0,"claimAddress":0}]}'
```

Comment: Does it work now?

Comment: Yes, it works now